# Obtener ubicaciones periodicas Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Alguna idea de como hacer para obtener las coordenadas de un usuario cada "x" tiempo incluso si la aplicación pasa a segundo plano esto sería en Swift. desde ya gracias.
Estoy basándome en un ejemplo que encontré pero solo obtiene las coordenadas cuando se abre y cierra la aplicación. que es este:

ViewController.Swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, LocationServiceDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var LocationTblView: UITableView!
var updatedLocation : [String] = []
var userDefault: UserDefaults!
let locService = LocationService()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setup()
}
func setup(){
    userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    self.updatedLocation = userDefault.array(forKey: LocationKey) as? [String] ?? []
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    locService.delegat = self
    locService.locManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}
func didLocationUpdated(_ locArr: [String]) {
    self.updatedLocation = locArr
}
}
```

LocationService:Swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
let LocationKey = "LocationKey"
var latitud = 0.0, longitud = 0.0
protocol LocationServiceDelegate {
func didLocationUpdated(_ locArr : [String])
 }
class LocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {
let locManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
var updatedLocation : [String] = []
var userDefault : UserDefaults!
var delegat : LocationServiceDelegate?

override init() {
    super.init()
    userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    self.updatedLocation = userDefault.array(forKey: LocationKey) as? [String] ?? []
    locManager.delegate = self
}

func saveLocation(){
    userDefault.set(self.updatedLocation, forKey: LocationKey)
    userDefault.synchronize()
    self.delegat?.didLocationUpdated(self.updatedLocation)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    self.checkLocatoinPermission()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    latitud = locations.first!.coordinate.latitude
    longitud = locations.first!.coordinate.longitude
    print(String(latitud))
    print(String(longitud))
    let currentLoc = "\(String(describing: locations.first!.coordinate.latitude)) \(locations.first!.coordinate.longitude)"
    print("\(String(describing: locations.first!.coordinate.latitude)) \(locations.first!.coordinate.longitude)")
    self.updatedLocation.append(currentLoc)
    print("Did get Update loation")
    self.saveLocation()
}
}
```

He leído que con un Timer después de cierto tiempo se detiene la tarea alguna opción sobre como hacer que obtenga las coordenadas cada 5 minutos por ejemplo.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de lo que has intentado para ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes setear una variable global con la hora adelantada los 5 minutos en el `ViewDidLoad`:

```
//Variable global
var horaMas5Minutos = Date()

override init() {
    self.horaMas5Minutos = Date().addingTimeInterval(5*60)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //verificas si la hora actual tiene 5 minutos más
    var hora = Date() 
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    if(calendar.dateComponents([.minute], from: hora) == (calendar.dateComponents([.minute], from: self.horaMas5Minutos)) {
        //Actualizas la ubicación
        //seteas la hora inicial con + 5 minutos
        self.horaMas5Minutos.addingTimeInterval(5 * 60)
    }
}
```